# Story Identification: short story where personified Evolution chases Design through time

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a fairly recent short story, published within the last five years I think.

Evolution is personified as a terrifying female monster, and she chases Design through time, passing through traps and enemies after him. He leaves behind a cyborg and other machines to slow her down, and a transhuman with cuttlefish eyes.

At one point Design complains that Evolution leads to nothing, pointing at the Black Hole era of stellar evolution and saying "These are what you think of as strong?"